# Dynamic Action Bar in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a ListActivity that populates its List rows using an ArrayAdapter. The list includes a checkbox that the user can select to make a multi selection.

I'm trying to implement something so that the action bar at the bottom changes based on the number of checkboxes checked. Example: A set of buttons if zero items are chedked, and a different set of buttons if there are multiple items checked.

Examples:

[image] [image]

What is the paradigm for doing this? I could put some code in my custom ArrayAdapter to track the number of items checked, but I'm not sure if this is the standard practive. Also, how would I dynamically build the Action Bar? When using the current GMail for android app by Google, it appears as if a seperate ActionBar is overlayed on top of the one used for having 0 emails checked.

Comment: Contextual Actionbar ... ok so start from [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual), then go [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) and finally end [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB)

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed this in the Developer guide. Feel free to change this to an Answer so i can credit you properly and close the question.